# Spark replicating rows with values of a column from different dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to replicate rows inside a dataset multiple times with different values for a column in Apache Spark. Lets say I have a dataset as follows

Dataset A

```
|  num  |  group |
|   1   |   2    |
|   3   |   5    |
```

Another dataset have different columns

Dataset B

```
|  id  |
|   1  |
|   4  |
```

I would like to replicate the rows from Dataset A with column values of Dataset B. You can say a join without any conditional criteria that needs to be done. So resulting dataset should look like.

```
| id  |  num  |  group |
|  1  |   1   |   2    |
|  1  |   3   |   5    |
|  4  |   1   |   2    |
|  4  |   3   |   5    |
```

Can anyone suggest how the above can be achieved? As per my understanding, join requires a condition and columns to be matched between 2 datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called `CartesianProduct` and `df1.crossJoin(df2)` will achieve it. But be careful with it because it is a very heavy operation.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I do have a few rows on the right hand side data frame. So I believe it shouldn't have huge performance repercussions. The entire data frame can be loaded into memory (I think broadcast joins will work here).